# Até que ponto engenharia reversa é um crime?

Tags: independente-de-linguagem, engenharia-reversa

A engenharia reversa é a prática de abrir uma nova tecnologia e ver como funciona "por debaixo dos panos" (não, necessariamente, produzindo algum conteúdo lucrativo com esse conhecimento). Porém eu vejo, em meu dia a dia, diversos elementos que vieram de engenharia reversa.

Um exemplo é o controle oficial da Sony para o PlayStation 2 e seus inúmeros similares, ou os famosos "hacks" para jogos.

Apesar disso, eu nunca vi um produtor de controles "similares" ou de hacks para jogos singleplayer serem presos.

Também tem o caso do PolyStation, que, apesar de vir de engenharia reversa do NES, e, por vezes, nem mesmo possuir os componentes originais, é considerado pirataria, ao invés de "similar".

Até que ponto, no geral, eu posso explorar a tecnologia alheia (abrindo, testando, e vendo como funciona "por baixo dos panos") sem que isso seja considerado um crime?

Comment: É uma questão intrigante, mas tenho minhas dúvidas se isso se enquadra no escopo do site, tal como a discussão sobre licenças. É algo que pode impactar diretamente o programador, mas a resposta tem natureza legal/penal, sendo necessária consultar um advogado ou profissão semelhante.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

E crime apartir que inflinge as leis de codigo pessoal ou seja imagine voce trabalhar em um projeto por 2 a 3 anos em um software e do nada o cara aplica engenharia reversa no seu trabalho e rouba funcoes e estudo de aprimoramento de suas funcoes e arquitetura de seu programa. Ex (voce dedicar e compilar um arquivo e derrepente o cara vem com um programa tipo ollydbg ou outros e rouba seus codigos com um bom e vezes maldito ctrlc + ctrlv pra tirar vantagem de seu trabalho sem permissao.

Se nao me engano se nao mudou as leis mundiais a engenharia reversa so pode ser usada pra estudo em bases e nao pra copia de arquivo.  No brasil esses estudo antigamente so podia ser estudado durante um mes no pc do estudante.

Comment: "esses estudo antigamente so podia ser estudado" isso aqui não fez sentido. E aproveitando que respondeu, conseguiria embasar a sua resposta com fontes oficiais ou documentos oficiais que embasam a resposta, para não ficar apenas no achismo?

Comment: Então, por exemplo, se eu aplicasse técnicas de engenharia reversa em um jogo em Java, como o Minecraft, para entender como foi feito o algoritmo de criação randômica de mundos, eu poderia, mas, se eu copiasse esse código para ganho pessoal, ou o distribuísse na internet seria crime, isso?

Comment: @ArthurSiqueira O problema pior é: primeiro você usa apenas para estudo, depois você tem uma "ideia brilhante" a partir desse conhecimento e cria outro jogo. Até que ponto você cometeu um crime, dado que sem o acesso "ilegal" à informação privilegiada você jamais teria essa ideia?